# "Simon says" in java

Tags: java, loops

"Simon Says" is a memory game where "Simon" outputs a sequence of 10 characters (R, G, B, Y) and the user must repeat the sequence.

Create a for loop that compares the two strings starting from index 0.

For each match, add one point to userScore. Upon a mismatch, exit the loop using a break statement.

Ex: The following patterns yield a userScore of 4:
simonPattern: R, R, G, B, R, Y, Y, B, G, Y
userPattern:  R, R, G, B, B, R, Y, B, G, Y

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SimonSays {
public static void main (String [] args) {
  String simonPattern = "";
  String userPattern = "";
  int userScore = 0;
  int i = 0;

  userScore = 0;
  simonPattern = "RRGBRYYBGY";
  userPattern  = "RRGBBRYBGY";

  /* Your solution goes here  */
  char s;
  char u;


  for (i=0;i<=10;i++) {
     s = simonPattern.charAt(i);
     u = userPattern.charAt(i);

     if (s == u) {
        userScore = userScore + 1;
        continue;
     }

  }

  System.out.println("userScore: " + userScore);

  return;
 }
}
```

And the system said:

```
Runtime error (commonly due to an invalid array/vector access, divide by 0, etc.).
```

Why my code didn't work?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of hard-programming the length of your String (just because before you should have finger counted it and you may be wrong) you could use

`for (int i=0; i < simonPattern.length(); i++)`

Happy coding

Edit: but it could alse generate an Exception, as userPattern could be smaller than simonPattern. You could check it by

```
if (simonPattern.length() == userPattern.length()) {
     userScore = userScore + 1;
     continue; // this is not really needed but it may if having more else-if
} else{
     break; // This will break the loop as soon as it finds a mismatch
```

}

Answer (score 2):

The error is here:

```
for (i=0;i<=10;i++) {
```

Change in

```
for (i=0;i<10;i++) {
```

Your string has length = 10.

Answer (score 1):

`for (i=0;i<=10;i++) {` will execute 11 times (0 to 10) and you only have 10 elements in your strings. Changing the line to `for (i=0;i<10;i++) {` will execute proper number of times and shouldn't throw any exceptions.